# Firefox Incorrectly Displays Image (CSS + HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am building a heroslider for a homepage of a website. I have used a light open-source slider as my template and subsequently stripped it of extraneous features, leaving only those that my task required. The problem I currently have is that it works properly in Safari and Chrome, but has trouble displaying in Firefox.

Here are the examples:

Chrome: 
[image]

Firefox:

[image: As you can see, in Firefox, the image used as a slide is not scaled with the slider itself. Instead, the browser displays the top left corner of the image that corresponds to the size of the slider at the given resolution of the screen]

As you can see, in Firefox, the image used as a slide is not scaled with the slider itself. Instead, the browser displays the top left corner of the image that corresponds to the size of the slider at the given resolution of the screen.

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here? Do I need some kind of a hack for Firefox? I can post CSS and HTML code below, if needed.

Code of slider.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Boompx jQuery Hero Slider Plugin</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="description" content="Boompx jQuery Hero Slider Plugin">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">

        <!-- [ Optional ] -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

        <!-- [ REQUIRED ] -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bpHS.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <div id="browser-status"> 
        Dear Web User, your browser is out of date! <a href="http://browsehappy.com/" target="_blank">
        Please Upgrade Your Browser
      </a>
      </div>
    <![endif]--> 

    <div class="container">

        <div class="bp-hs" id="demo-default">
          <div class="bp-hs_inner">
            <div class="bp-hs_inner__item" data-transform="scale">
              <img src="assets/img/slider/main/01.jpg" alt="Boompx Hero Slider 01"/>
            </div>
            <div class="bp-hs_inner__item" data-transform="rotate" data-origin="top-left">
              <img src="assets/img/slider/main/02.jpg" alt="Boompx Hero Slider 02"/>
            </div>
            <div class="bp-hs_inner__item" data-transform="rotate"  data-origin="bottom-left">
              <img src="assets/img/slider/main/03.jpg" alt="Boompx Hero Slider 03"/>
            </div>
            <div class="bp-hs_inner__item">
              <img src="assets/img/slider/main/04.jpg" alt="Boompx Hero Slider 04"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- [ REQUIRED ] -->
    <!-- Requiring jQuery and touchSwipe for the Homepage slider -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendors/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script> <!-- optional (required for touchSwipe option) -->
    <script src="js/bpHS.min.js"></script>

    <!-- [ Demo Script ] -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- [ Optional ] -->
    <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

code of bpHS.css:

```
/*
 * Boompx jQuery Hero Slider Plugin v0.1.0
 * Demo    : http://codepen.io/boompx/full/wBmeQb/
 * Github  : https://github.com/boompx/bpHS
 * Vendors : https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin
 * Author  : boompx.com - @boom_px
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item, .bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-bullets .bp-bullets_bullet {
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.bp-hs {
  height: 225px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .bp-hs {
    height: 450px;
  }
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item.is-active {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-origin="top-right"] {
  -moz-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-origin="bottom-left"] {
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-origin="top-left"] {
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="rotate"][data-origin="top-left"] {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-145deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-145deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-145deg);
  transform: rotate(-145deg);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="rotate"][data-origin="top-right"] {
  -moz-transform: rotate(145deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(145deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="rotate"][data-origin="bottom-left"] {
  -moz-transform: rotate(145deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(145deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="rotate"].is-active {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="scale"] {
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item[data-transform="scale"].is-active {
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-btn.bp-hs_control__prev {
  left: 30px;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-btn.bp-hs_control__next {
  right: 30px;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-bullets {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-bullets .bp-bullets_bullet {
  margin: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.bp-hs .bp-hs_control .bp-bullets .bp-bullets_bullet.current {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #2b2f31;
}
.bp-hs img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.bp-hs:hover, .bp-hs:active, .bp-hs:focus,
.bp-hs *:hover,
.bp-hs *:active,
.bp-hs *:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.bp-hs.has-touchSwipe {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.bp-hs.has-touchSwipe:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live link? Browser-specific problems are hard to solve without an actual website to open with browsers.

Comment: No. It is my local development.

Comment: I am using this slider as a starting point. You can see the same behavior there: http://codepen.io/boompx/full/wBmeQb/

Comment: Ah ok, much better. Check out my answer. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for this part in the css:

```
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    /* Then add this line */
    right: 0;
}
```

Or if you don't want to edit the library's css just add to your own css file

```
.bp-hs .bp-hs_inner .bp-hs_inner__item {
    right: 0;
}
```

---

The image is *positioned* correctly. It's not *scaled* correctly on firefox. The original image is much wider than the visible area of the slider. The `img` itself has `max-width: 100%` set to ensure that it will be scaled down in case its parent's width is smaller than its default size. The cause of the problem here: its parent (the `.bp-hs_inner__item`) doesn't have a width value set, meaning it has default css value `width: auto;`.

My guess is that Chrome consider `width: auto;` as "as much as you want, but no larger than your parent". `.bp-hs_inner__item`'s parent (the `.bp-hs_inner`) actually has a width set in its inline style, so that solves the problem. Firefox, on the other hand, seems to just consider `width: auto;` as "as much width as you want`. Thus the bug.

By giving `.bp-hs_inner__item` both `left: 0;` and `right: 0`, I force it to have the same width with its parent, thus giving is an actual width that can be compared against by the `img`. Another way to fix could be using `max-width: 100%;` instead of `right: 0;`. I think both method would suffice.

Comment: Could you explain what this does? I still have way to learn in CSS?

Comment: Urgh this is too long to write in comment. Wait a minute I'll update the answer.

Comment: No, I think I understand. It fixed the issue, by the way!

Comment: Ok, glad I was able to help :)